# Replace separator in a number with regexp

Tags: python, regex

I am using python and regexp and need to replace all thousands separator (,.) with en empty string ('') and only allow comma (,) as a decimalseparator or no decimals. So -

```
 - 1,500.55 -> 1500,55
 - 1.500.55 -> 1500,55
 - 1500.55 -> 1500,55 
 - 1,500 -> 1500
 - 1 500 -> 1500
```

It could also be some letters in the string which also should be replaced with an empty string -

To pay 1,500.55 -> 1500,55

I have a code like this but the code will faulty accept a comma as a thousand separator and not replace a dot to comma as a decimal separator -

```
cleaned = re.sub(r"[^\d,]+", '', clean_str)
```

It's about money so you can assume that if there are decimals (cent) there will probably be in two decimals.

Comment: This is impossible based on what you have described, because if the input is say `1.234` there is no way to know whether the dot is a thousands separator or a decimal point.

Comment: @alani, there's. Length.

Comment: @OlvinRoght No, just because the examples in the question have only two decimal places, there is nothing in th question that says how many there *could* be.

Comment: Its about money so there is not so much chance that 1.234 should be  $1 and 0.234 cent so this example should be parsed to 1234

Comment: @user2856066 That is new information and should be added to the question.

Comment: @user2856066, it's easy to do with 2 replacements, but if you want single expression - it will be really complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `sub + replace` code:

```
>>> import re
>>> reg = re.compile(r'[,.]+(?!\d{2}$)|[^\d.,]+')
>>> arr = ['1,500.55', '1.500.55', '1500.55', '1,500', '1 500', '1,500,55']
>>> for i in arr:
...     print ( reg.sub('', i).replace('.', ',') )
...
1500,55
1500,55
1500,55
1500
1500
1500,55
```

**Details:**

- `[,.]+(?!\d{2}$)`: Match comma or dot if it is not followed by 2 digits before end
- `|`: OR
- `[^\d.,]+`: Match 1 or more of any character that is not a digit, dot and comma
- `''`: Replace it with empty string
- `replace('.', ',')`: replace last dot with a comma

Comment: Have you tried the string 1,500,55. It seems to be the faulty answer 150055 and not the correct 1500,55.

Comment: check my updated answer.